# streamStatus as NSStreamStatusAtEnd

Tags: ios

## What may be the reason for getting streamStatus as NSStreamStatusAtEnd for NSOutputStream?

```
if(self.outputStream.streamStatus == NSStreamStatusAtEnd)
{
     // why this condition is true?
}
```

Comment: Is this a theoretical question or did that status actually occur? And what kind of output stream do you have, how is it created?

Comment: yeah, it actually occured. It it NSOutputStream